# Rails how to write model methods to query based on given parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to rails.

I want to run a query on my Flight objects based on the parameters submitted to the flights#index route. The parameters are departure_airport_id, arrival_airport_id, and date.

However, since the search form submits nil values as empty strings in the url (e.g. `params {date: nil)` submits as a url `.../flights/index/date=""`) I am having a hard time organizing my code in the FlightsController and writing helper methods in the Flight model to query based only upon the parameters that are not empty.

My first solution was to write helper methods in the model to perform query based on certain parameter only if the parameter is not nil or empty string; then, string all of those helper methods in the controller before passing the collection to the view. For example:

```rb
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
   
   ...

   def self.around_date(date_string, day_interval=1)
    if date_string == "" || !date_string
      return all
    end

    date = Date.parse(date_string)

    lower_date = date - day_interval.days
    upper_date = date + day_interval.days
    where(start_datetime: (lower_date..upper_date))
  end
end
```

```rb
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...

    if params[:date] || params[:departure_airport_id] || params[:arrival_airport_id]
      @pagy, @flights = pagy(Flight.around_date(params[:date])
                                  .from_departure_airport(params[:departure_airport_id])
                                  .to_arrival_airport(params[:arrival_airport_id])
                                  .order(:start_datetime))
    else
      @flights = nil
    end
```

This worked exactly as I envisioned. However, this seems very unorganized and inefficient. So I tried to make the helper methods (such as #around_date and #from_departure_airport) private, and create a new method in the Flight class:

```
def self.query_search(query_params)
    around_date(query_params[:date], day_interval=0) unless query_params[:date] == ""
    from_departure_airport(query_params[:departure_airport_id]) unless query_params[:departure_airport_id] == ""
    to_arrival_airport(query_params[:arrival_airport_id]) unless query_params[:arrival_airport_id] == ""
end
```

In the model therefore, I can reduce the code to `Flight.query_search(query_params)` and also use strong parameters.

This seems way more organized to me but it's not working. The query_search method doesn't perform all the queries from the helper functions and the controller always receives nil from the method.

My two questions are:

1. Is this a good way to organize my code for what I'm trying to do here?
2. How do I fix the query_search method to perform all the queries in each helper method?

Thanks. I'm happy to clarify anything I didn't put very well in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would improve readability by using two core features of [`ActiveRecord.scope`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

- They can be chained and
- when evaluated to `nil` then they return the `ActiveRecord::Relation` itself

That means instead of testing if a key exists in the `params` exist, I would pass its value to the scope and test in the scope if any filter should be applied.

```
# in the model
scope :around_date, ->(date_string, day_interval = 1) {
  if date_string.present?
    date = Date.parse(date_string)

    lower_date = date - day_interval.days
    upper_date = date + day_interval.days

    where(start_datetime: (lower_date..upper_date))
  end
}
```

And use it in the controller like this:

```
@pagy, @flights = pagy(
  Flight.around_date(params[:date])
        .from_departure_airport(params[:departure_airport_id])
        .to_arrival_airport(params[:arrival_airport_id])
        .order(:start_datetime)
)
```

Btw. you can use [`Object#present?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) to check is an object is empty or blank?